# php if condition with OR operator not working

Tags: php, strpos

I'm trying to check if the the url is `win` or `scholartips` when the script gets a hit.

```
<?php if (!strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'win') || !strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'scholartips') ): ?>
 conditional script here
<?php endif; ?>
```

But whenever i hit a url with `example.com/win/` or `example.com/scholartips/` the conditional script is still being loaded. What is wrong with my condition? If i delete 1 of the conditions the code work, but i want to target 2 url paths. Thanks.

Comment: `<?php if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'win')===false || strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'scholartips') ===flase ): ?>`

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the AND operator. example.com/win does not contain scholartips and because of the OR operator the whole clause evaluates as TRUE. So switch the || to &&.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using an && operator, not an or operator.

Whether you visit either /win/ or /scholarship/, one of those strpos checks will always evaluate to true.